# Insert id from table to another table in laravel +vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGKfe.png)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIN2A.png)

I want to get Id from students table where   i want insert this id in differs table  . I don't really know how to explain it but maybe if you see my codes, you would understand. I have already finish making the relationship between this 2 tables already

[my student controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD1Q3.png)
[this my differ controller but I do not know any idea about if this code true or no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amft0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should post your code not the image

Answer (score 1):

first: 'app\Differ'? but Differ is in App\Models
you can use `hasOne(Differ::class);` when Student model and differ in the same folder

the second thing you should know, when using functions of relationship in laravel such as hasOne, a foreign key should be named by student_id in Differ or
you show it in function like `hasOne(Differ::class,'id_student','id')`